# What is the relationship between conceptual engineering and social change?

Tags: ethics, social-ethics, concept, social-critique

I am currently doing research on the relationship between projects in conceptual engineering and actual, realized, social change.

Of primary interest to me is how, for instance, Haslanger's revisionary accounts of race and gender may help in accomplishing their intentions of ending social oppression. She advocates that we use the word "woman" differently, to reflect the oppression they experience. Are we to assume, however, that a change in our language/conceptual framework will necessitate social change? Why?

I suppose, in other words, what is it that is needed to "bridge the gap" between a change in one's concepts and change in the real world?

Comment: wishful thinking?

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy I suppose that could play a role! I more so want to look at what ways, if any, social developments can enable (and be affected by) projects in conceptual engineering.

Comment: [status functions](http://ist-socrates.berkeley.edu/~jsearle/290-04-01.pdf)?

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy I read the article. Very interesting. What I found most relevant was Searle's notion that governments, as systems of status functions, collapse when collective intentionality can no longer support them - the public withdraws acceptance of the system of status functions (p. 15-16). I am interested here in how such a change can occur - what is it that directly ties conceptual change to political change, here? Can you recommend anything else to review?

Comment: You might like this chapter on "[How We Create Desire-independent Reasons For Action](http://sallyhaslanger.weebly.com/uploads/1/8/2/7/18272031/john_searle_-_rationality_in_action-chap6.pdf)" and "[The Construction of Social Reality](http://epistemh.pbworks.com/f/6.+The+Construction+of+Social+Reality+(SCAN).pdf)" and "[Ontology and Social Power](http://ist-socrates.berkeley.edu/~jsearle/290-04-01.pdf)"

Comment: Oh, and don't forget [akrasia](http://www.naturalthinker.net/trl/texts/Searle,JohnR/John%20Searle%20-%20Rationality%20in%20Action-chap7.pdf)

Comment: Would you argue that any of these relate directly to how action/change is facilitated by conceptual change?

Comment: [yes](https://youtu.be/SVOuYquXuuc)

Comment: It sounds like you are saying the 'real world' is the majority of people's opinions on a subject, correct? Like when Socrates was discussing opinions in Platos Theaetetus, who's opinion is correct the majority or the one. Will a musicians opinion on a piece of music be more correct than a carpenter's, ect? Are both opinions correct? To changes one's opinion would be to educate the other to see the subject from a different point of view. I not sure that changing language would necessarily educate a person enough to change an opinion. Just my opinion :)

Comment: There are concepts, there are concepts that society at large will accept, and there are concepts that arise due to pre-eminent issues of the times. A concept alone isn't enough, it has to be palatable to people and not too far out of their experience to have utility value. For instance, in the early modern era good government was a pressing issue, so the world accepted it. So it's not so much 'how can I engineer society with my concepts', it's 'what concepts will society permit in their lives right now'.

Answer (score -1):

**The relationship between conceptual engineering and social change is based on tightening concepts along certain directions like amoebas, whereby it may be effected that the average citizen avoids certain unwanded aspects of concepts.**

Consider that you are in a swimming bath with springboards, and that by analogy, concepts are the springboards of thinking. The bouncing of the springboards makes it possible to effect great leaping figures in the air, before landing in the water. A concept may also contain such resonance possibilities, in many directions simultaneously.

If anybody has something against certain of these conceptual resonances, and has enough authority over mass media (Film industry, TV, newspapers, censorship in the internet), he may manipulate the everyday thinking of the thereof unconscious average citizen, by imbeding this concept in a kind of straightjacket, i.e. by contaminating the concept, or distorting it in a certain direction, like an amoeba.

If a citizen is in this sense continually provided with certain straightjacket-points-of-view, it appears him, as if it were a `“thoughtcrime”` (George Orwell) to think the opposite of this, i.e. the unconstrained concept. Hence for him, the concept’s resonance force in certain directions has got lost `(--> “crimestop”)`.